# how can i change menu view by user access role?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-mvc

I have  a web application project with MVC 4 and I use Telerik panel bar and bind it by site map for my menu.but now i want to each user according to user access roles in my  program see particular items of menu and hide remind menu items . how can i do this work in MVC any tips or trick would be welcome 
[this is link of Telerik website that i use it for creating my menu just i use it in partial view and just render its action in my layout razor code](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/panelbar/sitemapbinding)

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have this global class :

```
public class AccessControlList{

   public static bool IsAdmin {
       get{
         //put your code here 
         return false;
       }
   }
   public static bool HasOpenFileAccess{
       get{
         //put your code here 
         return true;
       }
   }

}
```

then in your view.cshtml you may have something like this :

```
@(Html.Telerik().Menu()
     .Name("mnuMain")
     .Items(itemAdder =>
     {
         itemAdder.Add()
             .Text("Admin Menu")
             .Visible(false)
             .Url("~/Home")
             .Visible(AccessControlList.IsAdmin);

         itemAdder.Add()
             .Text("Files")
             .Items(subItemAdder =>
             {
                 subItemAdder.Add()
                     .Text("Open File...")
                     .Url("~/Files/Open")
                     .Visible(AccessControlList.HasOpenFileAccess)
             ....
```

complete your AccessControlList class (AccessControlList.cs file) to check if the authenticated person has your required access or not.